# How to Refresh datagridview continously after Updating

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I am using This code for Updating my datagrid view after the data is updated in access database.The Data is updated for every second i kept this code in a loop in a background but when i am starting the background a big X is being displayed.

```
  try
        {
            OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter;
            OleDbCommandBuilder cBuilder;
            DataTable dTable;
            BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
        dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from data", cls_rt.con);

        //create a command builder
        cBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(dAdapter);

        //create a DataTable to hold the query results
        dTable = new DataTable();

        //fill the DataTable
        dAdapter.Fill(dTable);


        //BindingSource to sync DataTable and DataGridView
        bSource = new BindingSource();

        //set the BindingSource DataSource
        bSource.DataSource = dTable;

        DataGridView.DataSource = dTable;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
```

Then I used this code

```
        try
        {
            this.dataTableAdapter.Fill(this.rTDataSet.data);
        }
```

and kept this in loop

```
        dataDataGridView.Update();
```

then

```
        dataDataGridView.Refresh();
```

then

```
        dataDataGridView.RefreshEdit();
```

but it dint work for me

I want my datagridview to update for every second and one more thing when it gets update i dont want the whole gridview to update i just want the particular cell to be update.

Their would be a great appreciation if someone could help me.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Why would you update it every second? You can have a Repository, in charge of accessing the BL and to cache all data, in a bindable manner, and bind the DGV to it.

Comment: its a live data it updates every second that is why i want to update

Comment: can you say me how can i do it @YoryeNathan because i dont have any idea about what you are saying.

Comment: You must have something that is in charge of getting the live data and updating, right?

Comment: yes you are right that is why i want it to refresh for every second..

Comment: I mean other than the DGV. You should have some updating logic someplace. Make a class that is in charge of getting the live data into a BindingList<T>

Comment: can you give me some sample code or say me what i should change in my code.

Comment: First let me understand your situation as clear as possible. You are accessing the DB, so how is the data live? Is the DB being changed all the time? Who changed it?

Comment: I am downloading a file from my server and inserting that data in a database.and then i am updating the data by its symbol like UPDATE Data SET [Date]='2011-06-08' where [Symbol]='" + gold + "'; and i want my datagridview to display it after the update of data

Comment: You are downloading and then inserting into the DB with the same application? Please explain the whole thing thoroughly.

Comment: I am Downloading the data and inserting it into a database and updating the data for every second with the same application.I Just want to read the database after the updation completes and display it Hope You Understood.

Comment: Why won't you update the DGV when a bunch of data is downloaded? Download in bunches, as you do now, insert to DB, and update the DGV with the already-in-hand data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

almost all datagridview' s refreshing / updating the values will send you onto same way..and in this way the easiest of to "refresh" your dgv is to put this line when you need refreshing values

```
yourDataGridview.DataSource = yourDataRetrievingMethod  // in your situation your dataset and/or table
```